Excel: Lookup '1' and return multiple values
This seems rather simple be cannot currently find a solve for this.
I am currently in a spreadsheet, which has a column that is returning a binary value on the basis of random sampling.
I need to lookup the value '1', in this column and return all matching values from another 'item number' column in the same sheet.
I have tried XLOOKUP and Index Match, but they seem to just be returning the first value in the item number column, where I need each value returned in its own row.
Thanks in advance!
XLOOKUP, INDEX MATCH

"=if(A1=1,1,0)" and drag down.

Thanks Mike, I need to return the item number, not 1's and 0's though

How does your XLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH functions look? XLOOKUP will only return one value though, INDEX/MATCH can give multiple returns, but it requires a more advanced function ; possibly could you add some mockup data, using Table Markdown if possible.

You may use Table to Markdown Generator to make tables as markdown and post them in questions. Please, add data example and expected output

Perhaps you want to use FILTER, like so:
=FILTER(B2:B10,A2:A10=1)

This filters your list to only include the rows were Column A = 1, and gives you all the matching values from Column B.


FILTER returns all matching rows, like in the screenshot. Check that you are referencing the correct columns. Update your question with a screenshot like mine if you can.
